# Logging in GCP and locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-logging

I am building a system that is intended to run on Virtual Machines in Google Cloud Platform. However, as a form of backup, it may be run locally as well. That being said, my issue currently is with logging. I have two loggers, both work, a local logger and a cloud logger.

#### Cloud logger

```
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.oauth2 import service_account

CREDS = google.cloud.logging.Client(
        project=PROJECT, credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIAL_FILE))

class GoogleLogger(CloudLoggingHandler):

    def __init__(self, client=CREDS):
        super(GoogleLogger, self).__init__(client)

def setup_logging():
    """
    This function can be invoked in order to setup logging based on a yaml config in the 
    root dir of this project
    """
    try:
        # with open('logging.yaml', 'rt') as f:
        with open(LOGGING_CONFIG, 'rt') as f:
            config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
            f.close()
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    except Exception:
        print('Error in Logging Configuration. Using default configs')
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

#### logging.yaml

```
version: 1

formatters:
    simple:
        format: "%(name)s - %(lineno)d -  %(message)s"

    complex:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(module)s : [%(filename)s: %(lineno)d] - %(message)s"

    json:
        class: logger.JsonFormatter

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: complex

    cloud:
        class: logger.GoogleLogger
        formatter: json
        level: INFO

loggers:

    cloud:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [console,cloud]
        propagate: yes

    __main__:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [console]
        propagate: yes
```

I use `setup_logging()` to set everything up like so:

```
setup_logging()
logger = logging.getLogger(<type_of_logger>)
```

can be `"cloud"` or `"__main__"`

"**main**" only logs locally, "cloud" logs both to GCP Stackdriver Logs and locally.

Now if I'm not running on GCP, an error gets thrown here:

```
CREDS = google.cloud.logging.Client(
        project=PROJECT, credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIAL_FILE))
```

What is the best way around this? The `class GoogleLogger(CloudLoggingHandler):` always gets run, and if isn't in GCP it breaks.

An idea is to wrap the class in a `try/except` block, but that sounds like a horrible idea. How do I make my code smart enough to choose which logger automatically? And if running locally, completely ignore the `GoogleLogger`?

#### Edit (Traceback)

```
File "import_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from logger import setup_logging
  File "/Users/daudn/Documents/clean_space/tgs_workflow/utils/logger.py", line 16, in <module>
    class GoogleLogger(CloudLoggingHandler):
  File "/Users/daudn/Documents/clean_space/tgs_workflow/utils/logger.py", line 23, in GoogleLogger
    project=PROJECT, credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIAL_FILE))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/client.py", line 123, in __init__
    self._connection = Connection(self, client_info=client_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/_http.py", line 39, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(client, client_info)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: 1) If you use ADC (Application Default Credentials), Google Cloud client libraries will automatically choose which credentials to use. 2) One method to detect if you are running on a Google compute service is to try to read from the Google Metadata server. 3) Combine those methods to run code inside and outside Google Cloud.

Comment: @JohnHanley So when my logger is run, everything in my `logger.py` will be run. And that means it will try to instantiate `class GoogleLogger` and if it is not on the cloud it will throw an error and break. I can find out whether I'm local or on GCP, but how do I make my code skip instantiating this class if I am running locally?

Comment: Have added traceback of error in question when run locally.

Comment: Redesign your class. For example, don't do this `class GoogleLogger(CloudLoggingHandler)` Your class should not do anything until you call a function to setup the correct logging.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to bad inheritance.

Try to pass client into parent's `__init__` instead

```
class LoggingHandlerInherited(CloudLoggingHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(client=google.cloud.logging.Client())
```

Make sure that you have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in your environments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).