# GCP: Creating Client() object locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I have this class which is used for logging to StackDriver.

```
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.oauth2 import service_account

class GoogleLogger(CloudLoggingHandler):

    CREDS = google.cloud.logging.Client(
        project=PROJECT, credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/path/to/creds"))

    def __init__(self, client=CREDS):
        super(GoogleLogger, self).__init__(client)
```

When run on the google cloud, this works seamlessly. However, when run locally it breaks at `CREDS = google.cloud.logging.Client(project=PROJECT, credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/path/to/creds"))`

And my entire code breaks.

**Question:** Is there any way to skip instantiating this class if not on the cloud? Like a conditional class?

*OR*

**Question:** Is there any way to make this work locally? It should work. I give it the creds and the project and according to [StackDriver docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/go) if I give it the project + creds, it should work locally as well as in GCP?

When it breaks this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daudn/Documents/clean_space/tgs_workflow/utils/logger.py", line 27, in <module>
    class GoogleLogger(CloudLoggingHandler):
  File "/Users/daudn/Documents/clean_space/tgs_workflow/utils/logger.py", line 36, in GoogleLogger
    project=PROJECT, credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(local_or_gcp()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/client.py", line 123, in __init__
    self._connection = Connection(self, client_info=client_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/_http.py", line 39, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(client, client_info)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: What error are you getting when it breaks?

Comment: @MicahCarrick Editted and added traceback to question.

Comment: What version of `google-cloud-core` are you running? `pip show google-cloud-core`

Comment: `Version: 0.24.1`

Comment: @MicahCarrick Im going to update this, and get back to you. I have a feeling you may be correct cause I have version 1.1 on my compute engine instances.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545446/logging-in-gcp-and-locally?noredirect=1#comment105319507_59545446

Comment: @JohnHanley No Mr. John Hanley, this post answered my question. My local version was out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google added the `client_info` parameter in this change: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/7849/files#diff-340196d499e9d0eea25cd457f53bfa42L31

I suspect you are running a newer version of the Google Cloud Python SDK in your GCP environment and and older version on your local environment.

Comment: Testing this now!

Comment: Thank you, didn't cross my mind to check the version, this was the fix!